# Web-scraping interactive content python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am a small business and I am trying to collect the locations from

> https://www.irishconcrete.ie/members-directory/

so that i can then use this to load into my maps so i can visit each of them when i am near.

I have got onto python but i cant seem to web scrape the locations from this as you have to click to open to see the data

I can get access to the website and I can print it to excel but I don't know how to capture the data in an array.

I have python and selenium can install something else if needed.

Thanks

```py
import csv
from selenium import webdriver

count = 0 
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\O63308\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)


driver.get('https://www.irishconcrete.ie/members-directory/')

for i in range(1,176):
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="ListContainer"]/ul/li[''' +str(i)+''']/div[1]/a/div''')
    button.click()
```

Comment: Can you post your code trials?

Comment: See above - edited the original post

Comment: Can you confirm are you looking for something like this `['Sackville, Ardfert, Co. Kerry', 'Cave, Ballyhaunis, Co. Mayo']` this?

Comment: Yes along with the name like ['Ardfert Quarry Products', 'Sackville, Ardfert, Co. Kerry']

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since element is attached with page you can get the location without clicking on the button as well.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `presence_of_all_elements_located`() and following `css selector`

Then iterate those elements and get the `textContent` attribute of the element and do some string manipulation to get the `location` in a list.

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\O63308\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.irishconcrete.ie/members-directory/")

products=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[data-bind='html:$data.title']")))
print("Total Number of products : " +str(len(products)))
resultproduct=[product.text for product in products]
print(resultproduct)
locelements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".address+p")))
print("Total Number of locations : " +str(len(locelements)))
resultlocation=[locelement.get_attribute("textContent").splitlines()[0].split("Location:")[-1].strip() for locelement in locelements]
print(resultlocation)
```

**Output**:

```
Total Number of products : 175
['ARDFERT QUARRY PRODUCTS', 'AUSTIN GROGAN & SONS', 'BANAGHER PRECAST CONCRETE', 'BD FLOOD (CAVAN)', 'BD FLOOD (CROOKEDWOOD)', 'BD FLOOD (DRUMLISH)', 'BD FLOOD (KNOCKMANT)', 'BD FLOOD (OLDCASTLE)', 'BD FLOOD (RHODE)', 'BENNETTSBRIDGE LIMESTONE', 'BOGGAN SAND & GRAVEL', 'BOOTH CONCRETE (HEAD OFFICE)', 'BOOTH CONCRETE (PORTLAOISE)', 'BREEDON CEMENT IRELAND*', 'CANNON CONCRETE PRODUCTS', 'CARNAROSS SAND & GRAVEL', 'CARROLL QUARRY LTD', 'CASSIDY BROTHERS (BUNCRANA)', 'CASSIDY BROTHERS (CRANFORD)', 'CASSIDY BROTHERS (LETTERKENNY)', 'CASSIDY CONCRETE', 'CMC QUARRIES (GARRAFRAUNS)', 'CMC QUARRIES (MILLTOWN)', 'CMC QUARRIES (TUAM)', 'CONCAST PRECAST GROUP', 'CONDRON CONCRETE', 'COPPEEN CONCRETE', 'CORCORAN CONCRETE', 'COSHLA QUARRIES', 'DAVID K TROTTER & SONS', 'DOYLE CONCRETE (BUILDER PROVIDERS)', 'DOYLE CONCRETE (HEAD OFFICE)', 'DOYLE CONCRETE (WATERFORD DEPOT)', 'DRIMOLEAGUE CONCRETE WORKS', 'DUCON CONCRETE', 'DUFFY CONCRETE PRODUCTS', 'ESKER READYMIX', 'FARRELL CONCRETE', "FINBARR O'NEILL (HEAD OFFICE)", "FINBARR O'NEILL (OVENS)", 'FLANAGAN CONCRETE PRODUCTS', 'FLOOD PRECAST', 'FOGARTY CONCRETE', 'GLEESON CONCRETE', 'GLEESON PRECAST', 'GLEESON QUARRIES', 'GREANEY CONCRETE (SHANAGOLDEN)', 'GREANEY CONCRETE (TRALEE)', 'HANLON CONCRETE', 'HANLY QUARRIES', 'HARRINGTON CONCRETE & QUARRIES (GALWAY)', 'HARRINGTON CONCRETE & QUARRIES (MAYO)', 'HARRINGTON CONCRETE & QUARRIES (SLIGO)', 'HENNESSY CONCRETE', 'IRISH CEMENT * (DROGHEDA)', 'IRISH CEMENT * (LIMERICK)', 'IRISH INDUSTRIAL EXPLOSIVES *', 'KELLYS OF FANTANE', 'KEOHANE READYMIX (BALLYGURTEEN)', 'KEOHANE READYMIX (INNISHANNON)', 'KERRIGAN QUARRIES', 'KILCARRIG QUARRIES', 'KILDEA CONCRETE', 'KILKENNY BLOCK', 'KILLESHAL PRECAST CONCRETE', 'KILSARAN (BALLINAKILL)', 'KILSARAN (BALLINASCORNEY)', 'KILSARAN (BELLEWSTOWN)', 'KILSARAN (BROWNSTOWN)', 'KILSARAN (CASTLETOWN)', 'KILSARAN (CLONARD)', 'KILSARAN (DULEEK)', 'KILSARAN (ENFIELD)', 'KILSARAN (GALLSTOWN)', 'KILSARAN (HEADQUATERS)', 'KILSARAN (KILCULLEN)', 'KILSARAN (KILFEAKLE)', 'KILSARAN (KILLINICK)', 'KILSARAN (LUCAN)', 'KILSARAN (MILLENIUM PARK)', 'KILSARAN (NAUL)', 'KILSARAN (NAVAN)', 'KILSARAN (PORTLAOISE)', 'KILSARAN (ROSSMORE)', 'KILSARAN (SOUTH BANK ROAD)', 'KILSARAN (TALLAGHT)', 'KILSARAN (THE CURRAGH)', 'KILSARAN (TULLAMORE)', 'KILSARAN (WATERFORD)', 'LAGAN CONCRETE', 'LAGAN MATERIALS', 'LENNON QUARRIES', 'LOUGHNANE CONCRETE', 'LOUGHNANE CONCRETE (NENAGH)', 'MCGRATH CONCRETE PRODUCTS (HERBERSTOWN)', 'MCGRATH CONCRETE PRODUCTS (KILFINNANE)', 'MCGRATH CONCRETE PRODUCTS (O C MILLS)', 'MCGRATHS LIMESTONE (CONG)', 'MCGRATHS LIMESTONE (ROBEEN)', 'MCKEONS SAND & GRAVEL', 'MF QUIRKE & SONS', 'MICHAEL CRONIN READYMIX (CASTLEISLAND)', 'MICHAEL CRONIN READYMIX (KILLARNEY)', 'MICHAEL CRONIN READYMIX (MILLSTREET)', 'MOLLOY CONCRETE', 'MORTIMER QUARRIES', 'MOYLOUGH CONCRETE PRODUCTS', 'MULLAFARRY QUARRY', "O'CONNELL QUARRIES (ARDNACRUSHA)", "O'CONNELL QUARRIES (O'BRIENSBRIDGE)", "O'REILLY CONCRETE (BARLEYSTONE PAVING)", "O'REILLY CONCRETE (KINGSCOURT)", "O'REILLY CONCRETE (TRIM)", "O'ROURKE BROTHERS", 'ORAN PRECAST', 'P MORONEY & SONS', 'PATRICK MCCAFFREY & SONS', 'PLAZAMONT T/A DAN MORRISSEY (BRAY)', 'PLAZAMONT T/A DAN MORRISSEY (CLONMELSH)', 'PLAZAMONT T/A DAN MORRISSEY (RATHDRUM)', 'QUINN BUILDING PRODUCTS', 'QUINN CEMENT *', 'READY MIXED CONCRETE IRELAND', 'RHYNE ROCK', 'ROADSTONE (ALLEN, NAAS)', 'ROADSTONE (ARKLOW)', 'ROADSTONE (BALLINTRA)', 'ROADSTONE (BALLYADAMS)', 'ROADSTONE (BALLYEGAN)', 'ROADSTONE (BALLYGARVAN)', 'ROADSTONE (BALLYKNOCKANE)', 'ROADSTONE (BALLYQUINN)', 'ROADSTONE (BARLEY HILL)', 'ROADSTONE (BELGARD)', 'ROADSTONE (BENNETTSBRIDGE)', 'ROADSTONE (BLESSINGTON)', 'ROADSTONE (BOYLE)', 'ROADSTONE (BRAY)', 'ROADSTONE (BUNRATTY)', 'ROADSTONE (CAM)', 'ROADSTONE (CAPPAGH)', 'ROADSTONE (CARNDONAGH)', 'ROADSTONE (CARRIGTWOHILL)', 'ROADSTONE (CASTLEBAR)', 'ROADSTONE (CASTLEMINE)', 'ROADSTONE (CASTLEMORE)', 'ROADSTONE (CLASSIS)', 'ROADSTONE (DULEEK)', 'ROADSTONE (ENNISCORTHY)', 'ROADSTONE (FOYNES)', 'ROADSTONE (GALWAY)', 'ROADSTONE (HEAD OFFICE)', 'ROADSTONE (HUNTSTOWN)', 'ROADSTONE (KILCHREEST)', 'ROADSTONE (KILLARNEY)', 'ROADSTONE (KILLORGLIN)', 'ROADSTONE (KILLOUGH)', 'ROADSTONE (KILMACOW)', 'ROADSTONE (KILMUCKRIDGE)', 'ROADSTONE (LAGHEY)', 'ROADSTONE (MALLOW)', 'ROADSTONE (MIDLETON)', 'ROADSTONE (MILLSTREET)', 'ROADSTONE (MOYNE)', 'ROADSTONE (MULLAGHCRONE)', 'ROADSTONE (SHANAGOLDEN)', 'ROADSTONE (SLANE)', 'ROADSTONE (SWORDS)', 'ROADSTONE (TULLAMORE)', 'RYAN BROTHERS (ROADSTONE)', 'SHAY MURTAGH PRECAST', 'TECHRETE IRELAND', 'WEXFORD BLOCK', 'WRIGHT CONCRETE PRODUCTS', 'WRIGHT QUARRY PRODUCTS']
Total Number of locations : 175
['Sackville, Ardfert, Co. Kerry', 'Cave, Ballyhaunis, Co. Mayo', 'Queen Street, Banagher, Co.Offaly', 'Lavey, Co. Cavan', 'Crookedwood, Co. Westmeath', 'Drumlish, Co.Longford', 'Knockmant, Co.Westmeath', 'The Murrens, Oldcastle, Co. Meath', 'Rhode, Co.Offaly', 'Kilree, Sheastown, Co.Kilkenny, R95 EY0R', 'Kilmacree, Drinagh, Co.Wexford', 'Ballymullen, Abbeyleix, Co.Laois', 'Clonminham Industrial Estate, Portlaoise, Co.Laois', 'Lansdown Cement Works, Killaskillen, Kinnegad, Co. Meath', 'Tonroe, Oranmore, Co.Galway', 'Carnaross, Kells, Co. Meath', 'Knockcollier, Castletown, Aghafin, Portlaoise, Co.Laois', 'Gransha, Buncrana, Co.Donegal', 'Devlinmore, Cranford, Co.Donegal', 'Magheraboy, Letterkenny, Co.Donegal', 'Moyle Plant, Falcarragh, Co.Donegal', 'Garrafrauns, Dunmore, Co.Galway', 'Grageachullaire, Milltown, Co.Galway', 'Ballygaddy Road, Tuam,\xa0Co.Galway', 'Head Office, Hazelhatch, Newcastle, Co.Dublin', 'Arden Road, Tullamore, Co.Offaly', 'Coppeen, Enniskeane, Co. Cork, P47 E093', 'Ballinrobe Road, Buckwaria, Westport, Co.Mayo', 'Cashla, Athenry, Co.Galway', 'Manorhamilton, Co.Leitrim', 'Castle House (behind Pierce Hire), Cork Road, Co. Waterford', 'Hugginstown, Co.Kilkenny', 'The Old Mart, Old Kilmeadon Road, Co.Waterford', 'Bredagh Cross, Drimoleague, Co.Cork', 'Ballymaquirk, Kanturk, Co.Cork, P51 V024', 'Jenkinstown, Dundalk, Co.Louth', 'Athenry, Co.Galway', 'Stonepark, Endrim, Ferbane, Co.Offaly', 'Poulavone, Ballincollig, Co.Cork, P31 F991', 'Clashanure, Ovens, Co.Cork, P31 NH32', 'Feighcullen, Rathangan, Co.Kildare', 'Hilltown, Oldcastle, Co.Meath', 'Gurrane, Templederry, Nenagh, Co.Tipperary', 'Donohill, Co.Tipperary', 'Golden, Cashel, Co.Tipperary', 'Laffansbridge, Thurles, Co.Tipperary', 'Stokesfield, Shanagolden, Co.Limerick', 'Manor West Retail Park, Tralee, Co.Kerry', 'Lowtown, Robertstown, Naas, Co.Kildare', 'Laragin, Elphn, Co.Roscommon', 'Claregalway, Co.Galway', 'Kilkelly, Co.Mayo', 'Ballisodare, Co.Sligo', 'Sheastown, Co.Kilkenny', 'Platin, Drogheda, Co. Louth', 'Castlemungret, Co. Limerick.', 'Clonagh, Enfield, Co. Meath, A83 DY62', 'Fantane, Borrisoleigh, Thurles, Co.Tipperary', 'Ballygurteen, Clonakilty, Co.Cork', 'Dromkeen, Innishannon, Co.Cork', 'Killargue, Dromahair, Co.Leitrim', 'Kilcarrig, Bagnelstown, Co.Carlow', 'Bealnamulla, Athlone, Co.Roscommon, N37 XV88', 'Troyswood, Freshford Road, Co.Kilkenny', 'Killeshal, Daingean, Co.Offaly, R35 YK85', 'Ballinakill, Co.Laois', 'Ballinascorney, Brittas, Co Dublin', 'Mullagh, Bellewstown, Co.Meath', 'Brownstown, Kilcullen, Co.Kildare', 'Castletown, Rathmolyon, Co.Meath', 'Clonard, Kilrathmurray, Co.Meath', 'Annagor, Duleek, Co. Meath', 'Rathcore, Enfield, Co.Meath', 'Gallstown Quarry, Grangebellew, Drogheda, Co.Louth', 'Piercetown, Dunboyne, Co.Meath', 'Halverstown, Kilcullen, Co.Kildare', 'N74, Knockballynoe West, Co.Tipperary', 'Walshestown, Killlinick, Co. Wexford', 'Adamstown, Lucan, Co. Dublin', 'Grange, Lucan, Co.Dublin', 'Naul, Co.Meath', 'Proudstown, Navan, Co. Meath', 'Portlaoise, Rathleague, Co.Laois', 'Rossmore, Carrigtwohill, Co.Cork', 'Ringsend, South Lotts Road, Dublin 4', 'Tallaght, Dublin 24', 'Ballysax, The Curragh, Co. Kildare', 'Bunaterin, Tullamore, Co.Offaly', 'Slieverue, Co. Waterford', 'Milebush, Midleton, Co.Cork', 'Rosemount Business Park, Ballycoolin Road, Dublin 11', 'Bunnahowen, Ballina, Co.Mayo', 'Tullamore Road, Birr, Co.Offaly', 'Ardcroney, Nenagh, Co.Tipperary', 'Rathjordan, Herberstown, Co.Limerick', 'Ballycourtney, Kilfinnane, Co.Limerick', "Fortane Beg, O'Callaghan Mills, Co. Clare", 'Cregaree, Cong, Co.Mayo, F31 W425', 'Newbrook, Claremorris, Co.Mayo, F12 CF72', 'Culliaghbeg Sand Pit, Culliaghbeg, Ballinasloe, Co.Galway', 'Rangue, Killorglin, Co.Kerry', 'Castleisland, Co.Kerry', 'Coolcaslagh, Killarney, Co.Kerry', 'Millstreet, Co.Cork', 'Connolly Street Lower, Ballina, Co.Mayo', 'Belclare, Tuam, Co.Galway', 'Cloonascragh, Athenry Road, Tuam, Co.Galway', 'Killala, Co.Mayo', 'Ballycar, Ardnacrusha, Co.Clare', "Montpellier, O'Briensbridge, Co.Limerick", 'Ballieboro Road, Kingscourt, Co.Cavan', 'Larchfield, Kingscourt, Co.Cavan', 'Oakstown, Trim, Co.Meath', 'Poulregan, Castlebridge, Co.Wexford', 'Deerpark Industrial Estate, Oranmore, Co.Galway', 'Derra, Broadford, Co.Clare', 'Ballymagroarty, Ballintra, Co.Donegal', 'Kilpedder,\xa0Bray, Co.Wicklow', 'Clonmelsh Quarry, Carlow, Co.Carlow', 'Balleese Wood Quarry, Rathdrum, Co. Wicklow', '235 Ballyconnell Road,\xa0Derrylin, Co. Fermanagh,\xa0BT92 9GP', '235 Ballyconnell Road,\xa0Derrylin, Co. Fermanagh,\xa0BT92 9GP', 'Ballaverty, Riverstown, Co. Louth', 'Rhyne, Killoe, Co.Longford', 'Allen, Naas, Co.Kildare', 'Arklow, Co.Wicklow', 'Ballintra, Co.Donegal', 'Ballyadams, Co.Laois', 'Ballyegan, Co.Kerry', 'Ballygarvan, Co.Cork', 'Ballyknockane, Co.Tipperary', 'Ballyquinn, Co.Clare', 'Barley Hill, Co.Meath', 'Belgard Central/Belgard Weighbridge, Tallaght, Dublin 24', 'Bennettsbridge, Co.Kilkenny', 'Dorans Pit, Blessington, Co.Wicklow', 'Boyle, Co.Roscommon', 'Fassaroe, Bray, Co.Wicklow', 'Bunratty, Co.Clare', 'Cam, Co.Roscommon', 'Cappagh, Co.Waterford', 'Carndonagh, Co.Donegal', 'Carrigtwohill, Co.Cork', 'Castlebar, Co.Mayo', 'Castlemine, Co.Roscommon', 'Castlemore, Co.Cork', 'Classis, Ovens, Co.Cork', 'Duleek, Co.Meath', 'Brownswood, Enniscorthy, Co.Wexford', 'Joseph Hogan, Ballylin, Foynes, Co.Limerick', 'Two Mile Ditch, Tuam Road, Co. Galway', 'Head Office, Fortunestown, Tallaght, Dublin 24', 'Huntstown Quarry, Finglas, Dublin 11', 'Kilchreest, Co.Galway', 'Killarney, Co. Kerry', 'Killorglin, Co.Kerry', 'Killough, Co.Tipperary', 'Kilmacow, Co.Kilkenny', 'Kilmuckridge, Co.Wexford', 'Laghey, Co.Donegal', 'Mallow, Co.Cork', 'Midleton, Co.Cork', 'Keim, Millstreet, Co.Cork', 'Moyne, Co.Longford', 'Mullaghcrone, Co.Meath', 'Creeves Quarry, Shanagolden, Co.Limerick', 'Slane, Co.Meath', 'Feltrim, Swords, Co.Dublin', 'Tullamore, Co.Offaly', 'Toonagh, Ennis, Co. Clare', 'Raharney, Mullingar, Co.Westmeath', 'Stephenstown Industrial Park, Balbriggan, Co.Dublin, K32 W665', 'Castlebridge, Co.Wexford', 'Aclint Bridge, Carrickmacross, Co.Monaghan', 'Swanns Cross, Rockcorry, Co.Monaghan']
```

---

If you would like to do it in a single list try this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\O63308\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://www.irishconcrete.ie/members-directory/")

products=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[data-bind='html:$data.title']")))
print("Total Number of products : " +str(len(products)))
locelements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".address+p")))
print("Total Number of locations : " +str(len(locelements)))

results=[]

for product,location in zip(products,locelements):
    results.append(product.text)
    results.append(location.get_attribute("textContent").splitlines()[0].split("Location:")[-1].strip())

print(results)
```

Comment: Fantastic and thank you for helping me understand for the future